# Main effect after accounting for interaction - Type III Sums of Squares

Tags: anova

I am trying to understand Type I/II/III sums of squares.
Take for instance the 2 way Anova with 2 factors A and B.

I do not follow what Type III Sums of Squares are. In type III sums of squares we account for the main effect (say A) AFTER removing the effect of the other main effect(B) + interaction(AB). My query is : IF there is interaction, how can we have a main effect for A ? We would have simple effects for both factors and not a main effect.

Can someone clear my doubt ?

Comment: +1 you seem to be correct. Main effect  can not be ascertained in the said manner.

Comment: You have not mentioned why do you think like that. It may be useful to know the details.

Comment: I think I am incorrect. We can have interaction over and above the main effect of  variables A and B. So when we control for B and the interaction we get the main effect of A as if there had there been no interaction or effect of B. I am a little confused myself : ).

Comment: I understand  that the main effect  is the direct effect  and second or secondary effect is something like second-stage  or residual effect once you presume  existence  of interaction. There is nothing wrong with you.  The method to determine main effect - type III is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, please allow me  to rephrase. We assume that there is no interaction in type II SS. In type III we allow for interaction. This interaction is AFTER controlling for the main effect of A and B. Also the main affect is AFTER allowing for interaction. I think type III is correct.

Comment: First you have to contest my assertions. Give your model with  your definitions.

Comment: contd. it is unlikely that we can ascertain main effect s) without  knowing the interaction size and its behavior.

Comment: Imagine 2 almost parallel lines. We have 2 main effects and 1 cell with very small interaction. In this case we will have the 2 main effects + 1 cell where there is interaction. The main effect is what would have been had there been exact parallel lines. Type III SS would give us the main effects + interaction where the main effect is what would have been had there been no interaction. Type III IS correct.

Comment: First, we need an understanding of modelling the interaction. As I understand one of methods entails mathematical expectations and another is  probability of variables  affecting each other - the fixed effects modelling and  random effects modelling .

Comment: I was referring to a fixed effects model

Comment: My concern is how to model interaction itself prior to knowing main effect.

Comment: We build 2 models. One with interaction( A,B,AB) and one without( with A and B). See which one fits best. Then you will know if there is interaction after controlling for A and B.

Comment: I think that the naive procdure you want us to follow in statistics - definitely can not be recommended.

Comment: may I know your opinion on this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late on this thread, but Wm Venables wrote an essay expressing your suspicion about Type iii SS. For about 10 years after that, I was terrified of type iii anything

Bill Venables Exegeses on Linear Models
http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf

That's a lively read.